# Where does the slf4j log file get saved?

Tags: java, logging, output, slf4j, bin

I have the followed imports:

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
```

and the following instantiation:

```
private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Test.class);
```

and the following in my Main method:

```
logger.info("SOME MESSAGE: ");
```

However, I'm not able to find the output anywhere. All I see is that in my console there is:

```
21:21:24.235 [main] INFO  some_folder.Test - SOME MESSAGE:
```

How do I locate the log file?

Note that the following are on my  build path:

`slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar`

`slf4j-log4j12-1.6.4.jar`

I read the answer to similar questions but nobody actually says how to fix the problem.

Comment: slf4j is only an API. You should have a concrete implementation (for example log4j). This concrete implementation has a config file which tells you where to store the logs.

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle He builds with <code>slf4j-log4j12-1.6.4.jar</code> which means he is including an implementation.

Answer (score 63):

slf4j is only an API. You should have a concrete implementation (for example log4j). This concrete implementation has a config file which tells you where to store the logs.

[image]

When slf4j catches a log messages with a logger, it is given to an appender which decides what to do with the message. By default, the ConsoleAppender displays the message in the console.

The default configuration file is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">

  <Appenders>
    <!-- By default => console -->
    <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
      <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
    </Console>
  </Appenders>

  <Loggers>
    <Root level="error">
      <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

If you put a configuration file available in the classpath, then your concrete implementation (in your case, log4j) will find and use it. See [Log4J documentation.](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html)

Example of file appender :

```
<Appenders>
<File name="File" fileName="${filename}">
  <PatternLayout>
    <pattern>%d %p %C{1.} [%t] %m%n</pattern>
  </PatternLayout>
</File>

...
</Appenders>
```

Complete example with a file appender :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">

  <Appenders>
    <File name="File" fileName="${filename}">
      <PatternLayout>
        <pattern>%d %p %C{1.} [%t] %m%n</pattern>
      </PatternLayout>
    </File>
  </Appenders>

  <Loggers>
    <Root level="error">
      <AppenderRef ref="File"/>
    </Root>
  </Loggers>

</Configuration>
```

Comment: I have log4j on my build path don't I?

Comment: @user2763361 Then you should put a log4j configuration file in your classpath and log4j will use it.

Comment: What do I need to call this config file for it to find it?

Comment: @user2763361 You do not need to explicitly call it. Log4J tries to find it at its initialization. You only have to place the file in the classpath.

Comment: Where does the log file get outputted though?

Comment: @user2763361 I put an example with a simple file appender. As you can see, there is a `fileName` attributes which indicates which file to user to output logs.

Comment: Where do I input the filename? What's `${filename}`? Also there are two chunks of code. Do I combine them into the same chunk of code?

Comment: @user2763361 1) you have to replace `${filename}` with the path where you want to have the log file. For example, `c:\path\to\your\logFile.txt` or `/var/log/yourAppName/errors.log`. 2) Yes, you must combine the 2 blocks of code.

Comment: @user2763361 There are mainly 2 parts in the config files : *Loggers* and *Appenders*. Loggers tell which message to catch and to which appenders they must be forwarded. Then Appenders decide what to do with them. You should look at the doc for more information because log4j can do a lot of stuff for you and it would be too long to explain here.

Comment: I set the row to be changed to `<File name="File" fileName="/home/user/Desktop/logs.log">`, and removed the `...` in the second code block, combined them and pasted into `/src` as file `log4j.properties`. Then I hit CTRL+F11 in my main method and there was no log file outputted (still only output to console)

Comment: @user2763361 does log4j warn you that no config file was found? (it should be in the very first lines in the console)

Comment: It says `SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.` but that's it. But it outputs the logger to console properly.

Comment: @user2763361 You must solve this problem first because in this case, you are not sure that slf4j really uses log4j.

Comment: @user2763361 Are you sure that you do not have slf4j-simple.jar or slf4j-nop.jar? It would disturb slf4j.

Comment: In `Run configurations (on main method) -> classpath -> userentries` (Eclipse) I have `slf4j-api.jar`, `log4j-over-slf4j.jar`, `slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar`, `slf4j-log4j12-1.6.4.jar`. In `RightClick (on the project) -> build path -> configure build path -> libraries` I have `slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar` and `slf4j-log4j12-1.6.4.jar`.

Comment: @user2763361 Remove `log4j-over-slf4j.jar`. The binding between log4j and slf4j is already done by `slf4j-log4j12-1.6.4.jar`. Also remove `slf4j-api.jar`. You already got `slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar`.

Comment: Can I go the other way (remove 1.6.4 but keep the other one)?

Comment: @user2763361 I have never tried :). Provided that you don't have duplicates, it should not be a problem.

Comment: Sorry but what should I named the  configuration file, and where to place it? I create file name logConfig.xml or logConfig.config, place in main directory, build project to .jar file, and event place config file in same folder with .jar file when running project but log only showed in console, no log file being created?

Answer (score 45):

As already mentioned its just a facade and it helps to switch between different logger implementation easily. For example if you want to use log4j implementation.

A sample code would looks like below.

If you use maven get the dependencies

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.5</version>
    </dependency>
```

Have the below in log4j.properties in location src/main/resources/log4j.properties

```
            log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, STDOUT, file

            log4j.appender.STDOUT=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
            log4j.appender.STDOUT.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
            log4j.appender.STDOUT.layout.ConversionPattern=%5p [%t] (%F:%L) - %m%n

            log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
            log4j.appender.file.File=mylogs.log
            log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
            log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

Hello world code below would prints in console and to a log file as per above configuration.

```
            import org.slf4j.Logger;
            import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

            public class HelloWorld {
              public static void main(String[] args) {
                Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HelloWorld.class);
                logger.info("Hello World");
              }
            }
```

[image]

Comment: Do I need to put it in `src/main/resources`? Because I don't have `main` as a subfolder to `src`. So I just put it in `src`. Then I overwrote your `mylogs.log` to `/home/user/workspace/project/src/mylogs.log`, then ran `HelloWorld`, and it didn't output a log file in the desired location. (No error message just no output)

Comment: Yes, if its a maven project you would have folders created automatically /src/main/resources/.  Please see the screen shot above.

Comment: It's not a Maven project so I only put it in `src`.

Comment: Yes, you would put in /src/ folder.

Comment: This is a much cleaner implementation than writing it in XML.

Comment: this ans is the most complete one. thank you so much

Answer (score 4):

It does not write to a file by default. You would need to configure something like the `RollingFileAppender` and have the root logger write to it (possibly in addition to the default `ConsoleAppender`).

Comment: assuming OP uses log4j

Comment: @CeilingGecko See my other comment - he already states that he includes log4j.

Answer (score 1):

The log file is not visible because the slf4j configuration file location needs to passed to the java run command using the following arguments .(e.g.)

```
-Dlogging.config={file_location}\log4j2.xml
```

or this:

```
-Dlog4j.configurationFile={file_location}\log4j2.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

### Context

Responding to the:

> I read the answer to similar questions but nobody actually says how to fix the problem.

part of the question for `gradle` (instead of Maven).

### Instructions

To log towards a file at the root of your project named: `my-log-file.log`, using:

```java
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

...

private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Main.class);

...

LOGGER.info("This is an info message");
LOGGER.error("This is an error message");
```

The following 2 steps can be used:

### 1. Add the dependencies for outputting a log file to `build.gradle`

In `build.gradle` add:

```yaml
dependencies {
    // Allow logging to file.
    implementation 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.32'
    implementation 'ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.6'
}
```

### 2. Create the logging output configuration file

Create a file named: `logback.xml` and store it, as said the above answer, in:
`src/main/resources` (not in `src/main/resources/com/<projectname>/`). And it should contain:

```xml
<configuration>

    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
        <file>my-log-file.log</file> <!-- Specify the file name here -->
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%date %level [%thread] %logger{10} [%file:%line] - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
    </root>

</configuration>
```

That is it, if you now build and run your java program, you should see a file named: `my-log-file.log` at the root of your repository/project, with content:

```
2023-10-28 20:41:55,394 INFO [main] c.d.Main [Main.java:36] - This is an info message
2023-10-28 20:41:55,394 ERROR [main] c.d.Main [Main.java:37] - This is an error message
```

### Assumptions

This question assumes you already have a working `org.slf4j.Logger` setup that shows logging info in the terminal but does not store it to file.