# How can I print the error message into a txt or json file in my directory?

Tags: java

I have a function that save all the error in a errormessage list

```
public class Util {
    private List<String> errorMessages = new ArrayList<>();

    public void outputResult(String content) {
        logger.error(content);
        errorMessages.add(content);
    }
}
```

and my compare function add all the error message to the list,

```
public void compare(Config source, Config target) {
    if (source.getId() != target.getId()) {
        util.outputResult("id not equal");
    }
    // ...
}
```

And in my main function, I call this compare function and want to save all the error message in a txt or some other file in my current directory

```
public class MyClass {
    public void main() {
        compare();

        // writeToFile
    }
}
```

This is what I'm doing right now, I convert ByteArrayOutputStream to a string and print it, there a txt file generated but is empty, and I don't want to a string, I want each error message in the list be printed, how can I do that?

```
ByteArrayOutputStream errorMessages = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

try (FileWriter w = new FileWriter(pathToReport)) {
    w.write(errorMessages.toString());
}
File errorMessagesFile = new File(pathToReport);

errorMessagesFile.writeText(errorMessages.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

What `logger` library that you are using? If you use `sl4j`, you can couple it with `log4j` by configuring properly to just log the error messages into the file that you have specified in the configuration. I've done some lookup and I find this [stackoverflow: where-does-the-slf4j-log-file-get-saved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21881846/where-does-the-slf4j-log-file-get-saved) answer provided a template for you to follow on with this setup.